# Como usar dois scripts em um único select (onechange)

Tags: javascript, html, select

Estou com uma dúvida: Tenho dois scripts, um para trocar a imagem e outro do respectivo select, e outro para fazer o cálculo entre eles.

Gostaria de utilizar os dois para um mesmo select, o problema é que um é usado com:

```
onchange="processa(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'');
```

e o outro com:

```
onchange="processa();
```

Neste caso o que posso fazer para usar esses dois scripts, em um só select simultaneamente?

Script 1

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
/* URL of folder with images  */
var baseURL_OF_images = "file:///C|/Users/Vilma/Desktop/Developer/EloBurn/elojob/";
/* array of default image files */
var images =
      [ "bronze.png", 
        "prata.png",
        "gold.png", 
        "platina.png",
        "diamante.png" 
        ]

        function processa(imgNum,target){
        var z = parseInt(imgNum);
        var x = z - 1;
        var src = baseURL_OF_images + ( ( x < 0 ) ? "bronze.png": images[x] );

  document.getElementById("AvatarImage"+target).src = src;
  return true;
}
</script>
```

Script 2

```js
<script>
function processa(){
    //recolhe a informação dos select's
    var tipo_e = $("#tipo_esq option:selected").val();
    var div_e = $("#div_esq option:selected").val();
    var tipo_d = $("#tipo_dir option:selected").val();
    var div_d = $("#div_dir option:selected").val();

    //definir as arrays com as combinacoes e os respectivos valores
    var combinacoes = ['11','12','13','14','15','21','22','23','24','25','31','32','33','34','35','41','42','43','44','45','51','52','53','54','55'];
    var valor = ["15","15","15","15","15","20","20","20","20","20","25","25","25","25","25","45","45","45","45","45","120","120","120","120","120"];

    //definir as chaves
    var esquerda = tipo_e+div_e;
    var direita = tipo_d+div_d;

    //encontrar as chaves na array
    var pum = combinacoes.indexOf(esquerda);
    var pdois = combinacoes.indexOf(direita);

    var soma = parseInt("0");

    //verificacao dos resultados e mostragem dos mesmos se estiver tudo bem
    if(pum >= pdois){
    $("#erro").text("uma frase qualquer de erro");
    $("#valor").text("");
    }else{
    for (var i in valor) { 
        if(i >= pum && i < pdois){
        var vvv = parseInt(valor[i]);
            soma = soma + vvv; 
            var fim = "R$ "+soma+",00";
            $("#valor").text(fim);
        }
    } 
    }
}
</script>
```

Meu código:

```html
<img id="AvatarImage" name="AvatarImage" src="file:///C|/Users/Vilma/Desktop/Developer/EloBurn/elojob/bronze.png" style="widht:200px;height:200px;" />
<select id="tipo_esq" onchange="processa();">
    <option value="1" selected>Bronze</option>
    <option value="2">Prata</option>
    <option value="3">Ouro</option>
    <option value="4">Platina</option>
    <option value="5">Diamante</option>
</select>
<select id="div_esq" onchange="processa();">
    <option value="1" selected>Division V</option>
    <option value="2">Division IV</option>
    <option value="3">Division III</option>
    <option value="4">Division II</option>
    <option value="5">Division I</option>
</select>
<img id="AvatarImage2" name="#AvatarImage2" src="file:///C|/Users/Vilma/Desktop/Developer/EloBurn/elojob/bronze.png" style="widht:200px;height:200px;" />
<select id="tipo_dir" onchange="processa();">
    <option value="1" selected>Bronze</option>
    <option value="2">Prata</option>
    <option value="3">Ouro</option>
    <option value="4">Platinum</option>
    <option value="5">Diamante</option>
</select>
<select id="div_dir" onchange="processa();">
    <option value="1" selected>Division V</option>
    <option value="2">Division IV</option>
    <option value="3">Division III</option>
    <option value="4">Division II</option>
    <option value="5">Division I</option>
</select>

<div class="col-md-6" id="valor"></div>
<div class="col-md-6" id="erro"></div>
```

Atenciosamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa `.eventHandler` no JavaScript. Assim corres uma função cada vêz que um select na página mudar (o mesmo código único serve para todos) e dentro da função `processa` no exemplo em baixo sabes que `this` é o select e `this.value` é o valor escolhido do select.

```
var selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');
for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++){
    selects[i].addEventListener('change', processa);
}

function processa(e){
    fn1(this.value, '');
    fn2();
}
```

Comment: TE AMO. DEU CERTO! Outra dúvida: Como faço para $("#erro").text("Dados incompativeis, por favor, selecione corretamente."); Essa mensagem de erro desaparecer após selecionar valores validos? (ela não está sumindo)

Comment: @Filipe coloca `$("#erro").text("");` no inicio da função para apagar o texto. Se houver erro ele será introduzido na linha que já existe.